# Deny xmlrpc.php file but don't log the failed requests

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xml-rpc

I added this to `.htaccess` of a WordPress site:

```
<files xmlrpc.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

It works, when someone tries to access `http://example.com/xmlrpc.php`, this message is displayed:

> **Forbidden**
>   You don't have permission to access /xmlrpc.php on this server.

But still, the log displays (`less /var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Thu May 02 10:02:03.316061 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 19467] 
[client 1.2.3.4:49409] AH01797: client denied by server 
configuration: /path/to/xmlrpc.php
```

How to deny access to xmlrpc.php (possibly from .htaccess) but **prevent it to appear in the Apache logs?**

Comment: Rather than denying access to it you could use a `RewriteRule` to rewrite it to the home page? That can also be used to help hide the fact that it's a wordpress site.

Comment: @Nick Yes maybe, but more generally I'm interested to know how to deny access to a file, but avoid having the logs filled with these requests.

Comment: Would you care to explain why on earth one would want the log files to lie?

Comment: @arkascha I had too many such lines in the error.log (probably bots?) so I wanted to reduce the verbosity of these xmlrpc.php requests

Comment: Why would that be an issue? You do not read those files anyway, you scan then using grep or some more complex utility. Some GB more or less of log files do not really matter, do they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(xmlrpc\.php) - [F,L,NC]
```

Using the [F] flag causes the server to return a 403 Forbidden status code to the client.

The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

For more infos:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain in a few words what it does? What does - do? And F L NC?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, these 403 Forbidden requests are no longer present in the error.log!

Answer (score 2):

You probably know beter as I can see your over 19k reputation :)
xmlrpc is false as default in wp and not recomended to open global.
you should have something like this in`.htaccess` or in `functions.php`

`add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false')` rpc is disabled.

if not ? then add it to your `functions.php` it will solve your problem.
if didnt solve then use a plugin

**To deny from all** its beter to do it with a plugin like instead manuel [Manage XML-RPC.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-xml-rpc/)

İf you want to allow only for your self.
Check if you dont have rpc false in your `.htaccess` and add the code below to enable only for your ip.

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 10.123.456.000 //Replace with your ip
</Files>
```

Or allow only from **GET,PROPFIND,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,HEAD[403]**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST|PROPFIND|OPTIONS|PUT)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F,NS,L]
```

if you want to allow rpc then go here and follow the steps:
https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-XML-RPC-in-WordPress